# How to set a variable in kivy file with classes that are made in kivy file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm working on a project and I'm designing the setting screen.
I want to use it so many time so I made a class with variable such as content_cls
My Question Is How To Set This Variable With Classes That Are Made In Kivy File

`main.py`

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

from kivy.proeprties import ObjectProperty , StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("mainfiles\\kivymd2.kv")
class SettingCard(MDCard):
    right_text = StringProeprty("")
    content_cls = ObjectProperty()

class WidgetsManager(MDScreenManager):
     pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
     def build(self):
         return WidgetsManager()
    def on_start(self):
        SettingCard.add_widget(Setting_card.content_cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     MainApp().run()
```

`kivymd2.kv`

```
<Nav_drawer_header@MDLabel>:
    size_hint : None , None
    adaptive_size : True
    font_style : "H5"
    theme_text_color : "Primary"
    font_name : "mainfiles\\B-NAZANIN.ttf"

<Setting_card>:
    _no_ripple_behavior : True
    size_hint : None , None
    adaptive_height : True
    radius : dp(20) , dp(20) , dp(20) , dp(20)
    md_bg_color : "lightgrey"
    width : self.parent.width


    MDLabel:
        bold : True
        font_size : 35
        text : app.farsi_font(root.right_text)
        size_hint : None, None
        adaptive_size : True
        pos_hint : {"center_y" : .5  , "right" : .9}
        font_name : "mainfiles\\B-NAZANIN.ttf"

<WidgetManager>:
    
    MDScreen:
        name : "setting screen"


        FitImage:
            size_hint : 1 , .9
            source : "images\\download (8).jpg"
            pos_hint : {"top" : .9}


        MDScrollView:
            do_scroll_x : False
            do_scroll_y : True
            id : setting_scroll
            width : root.width
            height : root.height/10*9


            MDGridLayout:
                size_hint : None , None
                adaptive_height : True
                width : self.parent.width
                cols : 1


                Setting_card:
                    id : fast_setting
                    right_text : "شروع سریع"
                    content_cls : Nav_drawer_header
```

I Try to have a clean code and because of that I made that class And I Except to call classes in kivy file and put it in content_*cls but when I did this it said that Nav_*drawer_header is not defined

Pay Attention That I made an example for Nav_*drawer_header and I won't never use it as content*_cls

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - it means `SettingCard` instead of `Setting_card`. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `kivy.factory` for this. At the top of your `kv` file, add the line:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
```

Then, change the `content_cls` attribute in your `kv` file to:

```
content_cls : Factory.get('Nav_drawer_header')
```

This sets the `content_cls` attribute to the `Nav_drawer_header` class object.
You can then create an instance of `Nav_drawer_header` by using `setting_card.content_cls()`, where `setting_card` is that instance of `Setting_card`. Note that you cannot use `Setting_card.content_cls()` because `Setting_card` is not an instance.

So your `on_start()` method can be:

```
 def on_start(self):
     setting_card = self.root.ids.fast_setting
     setting_card.add_widget(setting_card.content_cls())
```

There are other errors in your code. Check your spelling of `Property`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a class and a class instance.  Think of the class as a recipe for creating an object.  In the code you have shared you are not creating the objects.

Looking on the on_start() method:

```py
    def on_start(self):
        sc = Setting_card() # instance the class
        sc.content_cls = Nav_drawer_header() # instance and assign
        ...
```

More importantly, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, or what the role is for content_cls.  If you want each SettingCard to contain a NavDrawerHeader you could do it all in kv:

```
Setting_card:
    id : fast_setting
    right_text : "شروع سریع"
    content_cls : ndh  # using id
    Nav_drawer_header: # instance added to Setting Card instance
        id: ndh  # id used to set content_cls
```